# Controlling Grid view pager Manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a situation, I have 1000 records in a table, I am only returning 10 records from that table which is getting binded on the gridview. Since only 10 records is coming out of 1000 from table but I want the pager of gridview to show <1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10>        1000 items in 10 Pages. When user will click on 2 next 10 data will be fetched from the table, when clicked on 3 next 10 data will be fetched and so on.

So my question is how will I control the numbering of pager of the gridview?

Comment: Add more detail about your code, including what you tried so far.

Comment: So far I have tried nothing. I want to control the pager of the grid view irrespective of the data that are binded. If data is only 10 then the grid view will consist of 1 page (PageSize=10) but I want 10 pages. When clicked on 2nd page more 10 data will get binded. My concern is how to have 10 pages if there are data for only 1 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `GridView Paging` by custom `Paging` as well `Gridview's` paging.

- [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/gridview-paging-sample-in-Asp-Net/) is the best example for `Paging` in `GridView`.
- Paging in GridView from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479347.aspx)
- [Custom Paging](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/) in GridView and from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/410733/Custom-paging-with-ASP-NET-GridView)
- [Paging](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Custom-Paging-with-PageSize-Change-Dropdown.aspx) with changing Page size

Hope this helps.